# Detect first or second file in a one-liner

Tags: perl

In AWK, it is common to see this kind of structure for a script that runs on two files:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { print "first file"; next } { print "second file" }' file1 file2
```

Which uses the fact that there are two variables defined: `FNR`, which is the line number in the current file and `NR` which is the global count (equivalent to Perl's `$.`).

Is there something similar to this in Perl? I suppose that I could maybe use `eof` and a counter variable:

```
perl -nE 'if (! $fn) { say "first file" } else { say "second file" } ++$fn if eof' file1 file2
```

This works but it feels like I might be missing something.

---

To provide some context, I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341696/2088135) in which I manually define a hash but instead, I would like to populate the hash from the values in the first file, then do the substitutions on the second file. I suspect that there is a neat, idiomatic way of doing this in Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `perl` doesn't have a similar `NR==FNR` construct to differentiate between two files. What you can do is use the `BEGIN` block to process one file and main body to process the other.

For example, to process a file with the following:

**map.txt**

```
a=apple
b=ball
c=cat
d=dog
```

**alpha.txt**

```
f
a
b
d
```

You can do:

```
perl -lne'
BEGIN { 
    $x = pop; 
    %h = map { chomp; ($k,$v) = split /=/; $k => $v } <>; 
    @ARGV = $x 
}
print join ":", $_, $h{$_} //= "Not Found"
' map.txt alpha.txt
f:Not Found
a:apple
b:ball
d:dog
```

**Update:**

I gave a pretty simple example, and now when I look at that, I can only say `TIMTOWDI` since you can do:

```
perl -F'=' -lane'
    if (@F == 2) { $h{$F[0]} = $F[1]; next }
    print join ":", $_, $h{$_} //= "Not Found"
' map.txt alpha.txt
f:Not Found
a:apple
b:ball
d:dog
```

However, I can say for sure, there is no `NR==FNR` construct for `perl` and you can probably process them in various different ways based on the files.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you're aiming for is to use the same loop for reading *both* files, and have a conditional inside the loop that chooses what to do with the data. I would avoid that idea because you are hiding what two distinct processes in the same stretch of code, making it less than clear what is going on.

But, in the case of just two files, you could compare the current file with the first element of `@ARGV`, like this

```
perl -nE 'if ($ARGV eq $ARGV[0]) { say "first file" } else { say "second file" }' file1 file2
```

Forgetting about one-line programs, which I hate with a passion, I would just explicitly open `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]`. Perhaps naming them like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my ($definitions, $data) = @ARGV;

open my $fh, '<', $definitions;
while (<$fh>) {
   # Build hash
}

open $fh, '<', $data;
while (<$fh>) {
   # Process file
}
```

But if you want to avail yourself of the automatic opening facilities then you can mess with `@ARGV` like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($definitions, $data) = @ARGV;

@ARGV = ($definitions);
while (<>) {
   # Build hash
}

@ARGV = ($data);
while (<>) {
   # Process file
}
```

Comment: The one-liner fails if the same file name is provided twice. The OP had the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create your own `$fnr` and compare to `$.`.

Given:

```
var='first line
second line'
echo "$var" >f1
echo "$var" >f2 
echo "$var" >f3
```

You can create a pseudo `FNR` by setting a variable in the `BEGIN` block and resetting at each `eof`:

```
perl -lnE 'BEGIN{$fnr=1;}
if ($fnr==$.) {
    say "first file: $ARGV, $fnr, $. $_";
}
else {
    say "$ARGV, $fnr, $. $_";
}
eof ? $fnr=1 : $fnr++;' f{1..3}
```

Prints:

```
first file: f1, 1, 1 first line
first file: f1, 2, 2 second line
f2, 1, 3 first line
f2, 2, 4 second line
f3, 1, 5 first line
f3, 2, 6 second line
```

Definitely not as elegant as `awk` but it works.

---

Note that Ruby [has support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937793/298607) for `FNR==NR` type logic.