# What is the Ruby equivalent of Awk's FNR==NR?

Tags: ruby, awk, command-line

Awk has the built in variables `FNR` and `NR` for the number of records (lines usually) read from the current file and in total.

In awk, it is common to have:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {first file lines; next } {process remaining lines } f1 f2
```

Commonly, `f1` contains values that determine how to process the remaining files. (key words, line numbers, etc.)

Ruby has the makings of a fabulous text processing language. Ruby has `$.` as the equivalent of awk's `NR` What is equivalent of `FNR`?

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$ head f?.txt
==> f1.txt <==
line 1
line 2

==> f2.txt <==
line 3
line 4
```

Ruby has the [ARGF stream](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/ARGF.html) (aliased as `$<` if you want to feel Perly) that either reads STDIN or opens a file from the command line. Same behavior as `awk`:

```
$ awk '{
    printf("FILENAME: %s, FNR: %s, NR: %s, %s\n", FILENAME, FNR,NR,$0)}
' f?.txt
FILENAME: f1.txt, FNR: 1, NR: 1, line 1
FILENAME: f1.txt, FNR: 2, NR: 2, line 2
FILENAME: f2.txt, FNR: 1, NR: 3, line 3
FILENAME: f2.txt, FNR: 2, NR: 4, line 4

$ ruby -lne '
    printf("FILENAME: %s, FNR: %s, NR: %s, %s\n", $<.file.path, $<.file.lineno, $., $_)
' f?.txt
FILENAME: f1.txt, FNR: 1, NR: 1, line 1
FILENAME: f1.txt, FNR: 2, NR: 2, line 2
FILENAME: f2.txt, FNR: 1, NR: 3, line 3
FILENAME: f2.txt, FNR: 2, NR: 4, line 4
```

If you want to read both `STDIN` and a file, you would use a `-` for a file placeholder:

```
$ echo '123' | awk '1' - <(echo 456)
123
456
$ echo '123' | awk '1' <(echo 456) -
456
123

$ echo '123' | ruby -lne 'puts $_' - <(echo 456)
123
456
$ echo '123' | ruby -lne 'puts $_' <(echo 456) -
456
123
```

Some more corresponding variables:

```
╔══════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════╗
║   awk    ║       ruby        ║                 comment                 ║
╠══════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ $0       ║ $_                ║ unsplit record (line usually)           ║
║ NF       ║ $F.length         ║ Number of fields from autosplit         ║
║ FNR      ║ ARGF.file.lineno  ║ Number records read from current source ║
║ NR       ║ ARGF.lineno or $. ║ Total number of records so far          ║
║ (magic)  ║ ARGF or $<        ║ stream from either STDIN or a file      ║
║ $1..$NF  ║ $F[0]..$F[-1]     ║ First to last field from autosplit      ║
║ FS       ║ $;                ║ Input field separator                   ║
║ RS       ║ $/                ║ Input record separator                  ║
║ FILENAME ║ $<.file.path      ║ Filename of file being processed        ║
╚══════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

So if you has a list of line numbers in `f1` and a text file that you wanted to index with those line numbers (something you would use `awk` or `sed` to do) it is possible to use Ruby.

Given:

```
$ echo "1
2
44
2017" >f1
$ seq 10000 | awk '{print "Line", $1}' >f2
```

In `awk` you would do:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{ln[$1]; next} 
       FNR in ln'    f1 f2
```

In Ruby you could do:

```
$ ruby -lane 'BEGIN{h=Hash.new}
              if $<.file.lineno == $<.lineno
                 h[$F[0].to_i]=true
                 next
              end
              puts $_ if h[$<.file.lineno]' f1 f2
```

Both print:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 44
Line 2017
```

The awk version of this example is roughly 5x faster (go awk) but the Ruby version would easily support inputs that awk couldn't, such as JSON, XML, complex csv, etc.

If you want the equivelent of `awk -v [same variable]` in Ruby, use multiple `-e` command execute lines in Ruby.

To print the `n` line of a file in awk with `n` being a shell variable:

```
awk -v n="${sh_n}" 'FNR==n{print; exit}' big_file.txt
```

or:

```
awk 'FNR==n{print; exit}' n="${sh_n}" big_file.txt
```

To do the same in Ruby, ie, pass the value of `${sh_n}` to the Ruby program you can do:

```
ruby -e "n=${sh_n}.to_i" -e '$<.each_line{|line| if $.==n then puts line; exit(0) end}' big_file.txt
```

[HERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables) is a list of predefined Ruby variables.

[HERE](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/globals_rdoc.html#label-Pre-defined+global+constants) is a list of global variables

Comment: FYI GNU awk has an XML parser and a CSV parser is under development. No JSON in the forecast AFAIK. See https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/gawkextlib.html for other formats gawk has a parser for.