# How to pass text file as an argument in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file, text

I need to pass a text file as an argument instead of opening it inside the code. The content of the text file should print on console. I have done the following code:

```
File.open("test_list.txt").each do |line|
    puts line
end
```

Please advice.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to pass a string that is the contents of the file? If so, and `s` is that string, just `puts s`.

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Do you want to read a file's content from `stdin` and print each line of that or do you want to read the file name and open that and print it?

Comment: I need to pass test_list.txt as an argument and if i run following code in console it should print contents of the text file, cat test_list.txt | ruby foo.rb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your shell, invoke the `ruby` script followed by the name of the `.txt` file, like this:

```
ruby foo.rb test_list.txt
```

The variable `ARGV` will contain references to all the arguments you've passed when invoking the `ruby` interpreter. In particular, `ARGV[0] = "test_list.txt"`, so you can use this instead of hardcoding the name of the file:

```
File.open(ARGV[0]).each do |line|
    puts line
end
```

On the other hand, if you want to pass the **content** of the file to your program, you can go with:

`cat test_list.txt | ruby foo.rb`

and in the program:

```
STDIN.each_line do |line|
    puts line
end
```

Comment: I'll add following code ,File.open(ARGV[0]).each do |line|
    puts line
end and can I pass the argument like cat test_list.txt | ruby foo.rb ?

Comment: Was the solution you were looking for?

Comment: No, if you add that code, you have to run `ruby foo.rb test_list.txt`. You'll then read the content of the file inside the program.

Comment: Read about [ARGF](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/ARGF.html) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44937793/298607)

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has Perl / awk / sed roots. Like Perl and awk, you can use the 'magic' of either reading stdin or opening a file name if that is supplied on the command line with the same code.

Given:

```
$ cat file
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

You can write a `cat` like utility that will open a named file:

```
$ ruby -lne 'puts $_' file
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Or, same code, will read stdin line by line:

```
$ cat file | ruby -lne 'puts $_'
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

In this particular case, it is from the `-lne` command line arguments to Ruby.

```
 -n             Causes Ruby to assume the following loop around your
                script, which makes it iterate over file name arguments
                somewhat like sed -n or awk.

                      while gets
                        ...
                      end

 -l             (The lowercase letter ``ell''.)  Enables automatic line-
                ending processing, which means to firstly set $\ to the
                value of $/, and secondly chops every line read using
                chop!.

 -e command     Specifies script from command-line while telling Ruby not
                to search the rest of the arguments for a script file
                name.
```

You can also do:

```
$ ruby -pe '' file 
# same
```

Without using the `-n` switch, you can also use the [ARGF](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/ARGF.html) stream and modify your code so that it will either use `stdin` or a named file in the same way.

Named file:

```
$ ruby -e '$<.each_line do |line|
    puts line
end' file
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Read `stdin` with same code:

```
$ cat file | ruby -e '$<.each_line do |line|
    puts line
end' 
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Or open the file named as a command line argument:

```
ruby -e 'ARGV.each{|arg| 
    puts "\"#{File.expand_path(arg)}\" contains:"
    puts File.open(arg).read
}
' file 
"/tmp/file" contains:
line 1
line 2
line 3
```